# Check highest div and apply to sibling

Tags: jquery

I need to check through each parent div, find highest child, and apply the height to all child beyond the same parent only.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

jquery that not working on my html:

```
var maxHeight = -1;
$('.parent>.child').each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
}); 
$('.child').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try to clear up the question a bit please? It's hard to understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to iterate over each `rows` first and then check its `children` element,

```
var maxHeight = -1;

$('.parent').each(function() {
    $(this).children(".child").each(function(){ 
       maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    }).height(maxHeight);
    maxHeight = -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop each `.parent` separately

```
$('.parent').each(function () {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    var $children = $(this).children('.child');
    $children.each(function () {
        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
    $children.height(maxHeight);
})
```